# How do I get the object color?

Tags: unity, color

I want to get the object color, when I start the game. How do I do this?

[image]

```
public Renderer cube;
public float r,b,g,a;

void Start() {
            r = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =
            b = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =
            g = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =
            a = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =

}
```

Comment: Did you try grabbing `color.r`, `color.g`, etc?

Comment: We solve this, check please "Shuvro Sarkar" answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its actually simple. Just use Color32 class to get the r, b, g, a of your desired gameobject. Here is an Example Code. Here I used a cube gameobject and got the color of its material.

```
public class FirstScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
// Use this for initialization
  void Start () 
  {
    Color32 objColor;
    objColor = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;

    print(objColor.r + " "+ objColor.g + " "+ objColor.b+ " "+ objColor.a + " ");
  }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This answer is correct for the most simple case, but sometimes you have an object with multiple materials. Then you need to pick the right one from the [`renderer.materials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) array. Also, your material might use a more complex shader which has more than one color. Then you need to use the [`material.GetColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetColor.html) method to get the color you want.

Comment: In Order to get the color on the screen one could also use render texture with pixel get access and use worldtoscreenpoint to get the pixel positions of the object. Then the exact pixel color can be extracted. However this will also introduce shadows etc.. But in some more sophisticated cases (where simple material access would yield wrong results) this could work.